# Is there an advantage to obsoleting Activities in ClearCase UCM streams

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

We are in the process of obsoleting a huge amount of ClearCase UCM projects, streams, branches etc. Is there a benefit of also obsoleting activities within the streams?

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage of a [`cleartool lock -obs`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lock.htm) is making sure the commands/GUI listing those objects don't show by default the obsolete ones.
([See FAQ](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21248532))

That is why you would obsolete branches or streams, labels or baselines: the graphical lsvtree will be much snappier without having to list all those objects.

But activities? That would matter if those activities are still presented as a choice when you checkout a file. If they are not (because, for instance, their stream is already obsolete), then it won't have a huge impact.
See "[What do we need to lock/obsolete to discontinue a project?](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013747762)"

Comment: Thanks for the input. We just have a huge monolithic VOB that has 10 years of projects/history that will never be looked at again. I want to eliminate those from displaying when joining valid projects, and don't want them to show on version trees as well. I was just wondering how deep we needed to go with the obsoleting to improve performance. It seems activities doesn't buy us much. As it stands we obsoleted 3 or 4 dozen projects, and within those about 1800+ streams. We're working on obsoleting the branches.

Comment: @JonShanks yes, obsoleting branches (and associated streams) as well as baselines will help keeping the version tree snappy.

Answer (score 0):

Another consideration is the number of activities/streams/projects in question. If you're -obsoleting something like 90% of the activities, then you may want to retire the streams in question and create new ones. If you're doing that to 90% of the streams in a project, you might want to consider retiring the project and creating a new one.

an obsolete lock does not prevent the objects in question from being looked up (to get the list of activities in a stream, for example) it just prevents them from being displayed by default in the GUI or on the command line.